# No output result while calling Django rest api using angularJs

Tags: html, angularjs

2 servers are running my machine. 1st one is django server, running with Ip and port (ex:http://IpNumber:5050/ids/). When i navigate to that url, Api is displaying. 2nd server is apache, running with localhost(ex:http://localhost:90/). From localhost I am calling above django rest api using angularJs. But I am getting nothing, even in developer tools also no errors showing. Please check below code and give me valuable suggestions.

```js
var myApp = angular.module("myModule",[]);

var getData = function($scope,$http){

  var url = "http://IpNumber:5050/ids";
  $http.jsonp(url)
    .then(function(data){
        $scope.emps = data.data;
    });
}

myApp.controller('getData',getData);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <script src="scripts/angularJs/angular.js"></script>
        <script src="angularJs/api_test.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body ng-app="myModule">        
        <div ng-controller="getData">
            <div>{{ emps }}</div>                                   
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do you see any errors in the console? Did you [enable CORS](https://enable-cors.org/) in port 90?

Comment: Sorry for the delay. Its night time in India. I checked in browser console. No errors are showing there. And in django i used CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True. I dont know how to enable CORS client side. Please guide me.